# Using ifelse statement to rbind conditionally to dataframe -- R

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a for loop that goes through a directory of Excel files, averages rows of data, and adds the averaged data to a new dataframe.  I'm trying to use an `ifelse()` function to fill that row with an error message if a condition isn't met.  Here's my for loop, so far:

```
error=rep(">3 Obs",times=55)

  for (i in 1:length(ExcelFileList){
     excel.file=paste(
        excelpath,ExcelFileList[i],sep="")
     tempdf=readWorksheetFromFile(excel.file, sheet=1, 
        startRow=10, endRow=0, startCol=1, header=FALSE)
     names(tempdf)=header   ## header is a vector of 56 character strings created 
                            #  above; the relevant one to this for loop is the first 
                            # one, called "Obs"
     x=round(colMeans(tempdf[,-2]),3)  ## this creates the vector I want to keep in 
                                       # the summary dataframe "Flux", ignoring            
                                       # column 2 which is a character vector
     Flux=ifelse(x["Obs"==2.000],rbind(x,Flux),rbind(error,Flux))  ## When the    
                    # average of Obs is 2, that means there were 3 observations.  In 
                    # this case, I want to add the vector to the summary dataframe 
                    # Flux; if there are more or less than 3, I want to return an error but still fill the row as a place holder.
      )
   }
```

I'm not sure if `ifelse()` is the appropriate function to use to choose whether or not to add the vector to the dataframe.  If it isn't, I'm happy to learn something else!

Thanks so much!

Comment: For starters, you need to close `for` before the opening curly brace, e.g. `for(i in 1:length(ExcelFileList)) {`. Also, it's not clear what your question is. I assume an error is being thrown (there definitely would be one, given the misplaced `)`), but it helps if you make your question explicit.

Comment: I also suspect you want `x["Obs"]==2`, assuming you want to compare the `x["Obs"]` vector to `2`. Otherwise, `x["Obs"==2.000]` compares the string `Obs` to `2`, leading to `x[FALSE]`.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want `ifelse()` as it's made to operate on vectors and return vectors of the same length. For this, you just want `if` and `else` separately.